# How to identify tabs automatically without mentioning xpath of individual tabs

Tags: xpath, robotframework

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have the main tab libraries and within libraries i have two more tabs Communication,Innovation,as of now i have written a script to identify each tabs individually but i want to write a script so that it identifies the script by itself.This is my code:

```
 Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=.//*[text()='LIBRARIES']
    Click Element     xpath=.//*[text()='LIBRARIES']
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=.//*[contains(text(),'Communication')]
    Click Element    xpath=.//*[contains(text(),'Communication')]
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=.//*[text()='Sisterhood of Motherhood']
    Click Element   xpath=.//*[text()='Sisterhood of Motherhood']
    Click Image    xpath=.//img[@ src='pmm/skinnedImage/abbott/close/skinned-image.png']
```

Comment: Can you expand?  Basically you've got this working as you want but you want to make it generic so it can be applied elsewhere I'm guessing?  As a side point, if this is going to be a regular activity, I'd suggest you work with the devs to build in meaningful identifiers

Comment: yes the above script is running fine but i am giving the xpath for each tabs but now i want the script to automatically identify the tabs itself and click and verify.I am not sure how i need to write the script for that in pycharm as am very new to pycharm

Comment: what do u want me to expand?

Comment: will the number of children always be the same or differ?  Will it be dynamic?  Or is this literally the only place this issue needs solved?  Some brief suggestions, work with devs to define meaningful ids/classes for these.  I imagine you could do a count on div elements of a certain class/id beneath the libraries xpath.

Comment: They do differ and yes they are dynamic How should i use devs?

Comment: Well you can do it yourself if you have access to the code base, but I would advise you to use unique ids or a set of classes which apply only to those ui elements.  Then they're very easily targeted as a group in your script

Comment: I tried using this:@{ENTRIES} = Get Elements xpath

FOR ${ENTRY} in @{ENTRIES}:
    Click Element    ${ENTRY} but am not sure how i should use it

Comment: I really would advise showing images of the problem and including any further code that is relevant.  You still haven't answered if this is an isolated issue or this is something you will be doing several times.  Currently I cannot help you as I do not fully understand your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85419/discussion-between-vdev-and-shicky).

Comment: Please find my screenshot attached

Comment: Please find my screenshot attached and actually in my application i have various tabs wherein as of now i have passed the xpaths of each tabs and thereby it clicks but i want to make it in such a way that it automatically checks the tabs in each heading and clicks all tabs itself without me passing the xpaths individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. What I have done in the past is:

1. Locate their parent element; let us call it **parentElement**
2. Those tabs will have to share some similar attributes such as class names, find out those common class names, say they are all called "class = 'x-container'"
3. locate all elements under parentElement that share the same attribute, in this case, class name, using a method **find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='x-container']")** to find all tabs under parentElement, they will be returned to you in a list,
4. using a "for" loop to go through this list one element at a time, this way, you will have access to all tabs without explicitly naming everyone of them.
5. But robot framework does not have a keyword that allows you to locate elements that are children of a common parentElement.
6. So you will have to create your own keyword from low level.

You can use Xpath if you prefer Xpath over CSS Selector. I am using Python as the example above.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment!